# Раздел /tmp linux

Tags: linux, tmpfs

Пытался поставить qtcreator с помощью  online installer-a. Online installer говорит, что не хватает места. Доступно 1.7ГБ, а требуется 3.6Гб. Я в непонятках(у меня 120ГБ, из них 110 свободно). Нарыл, с помощью

```
df -h
```

и

```
sudo dmsetup ls --tree
```

Что 1.69ГБ доступно только в /tmp. А в /tmp какого-то черта смонтирован... Я не знаю точно что это, в общем, посмотрите, вы, наверно, поймете.
Вывод `sudo dmsetup ls --tree`

```
umdw--vg-home (254:4)
 └─ (8:3)
umdw--vg-swap_1 (254:1)
 └─ (8:3)
umdw--vg-root (254:0)
 └─ (8:3)
umdw--vg-tmp (254:3)
 └─ (8:3)
umdw--vg-var (254:2)
 └─ (8:3)
```

Вывод df -h

```
    Файловая система          Размер Использовано  Дост Использовано% Cмонтировано в
udev                        1,9G            0  1,9G            0% /dev
tmpfs                       3,0G         1,6M  3,0G            1% /run
/dev/mapper/umdw--vg-root    11G         4,9G  5,6G           47% /
tmpfs                       1,9G          30M  1,9G            2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       5,0M            0  5,0M            0% /run/lock
tmpfs                       1,9G            0  1,9G            0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                   473M          80M  370M           18% /boot
/dev/mapper/umdw--vg-tmp    1,8G         5,7M  1,7G            1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                   511M         140K  511M            1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/umdw--vg-var    2,3G         288M  1,9G           14% /var
/dev/mapper/umdw--vg-home   100G         216M   95G            1% /home
tmpfs                       382M         100K  382M            1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                        10G            0   10G            0% /space
```

И получается, что online installer использует при установке /tmp, а там места нет, потому что там смотирован /dev/mapper/umdw--vg-tmp. Как мне его расширить-то ? Я хз. Учитывая, что

```
sudo mount -o remount,size=10G /tmp
```

выдает `mount: /tmp: mount point not mounted or bad option.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему так:

```
sudo mkdir /space     //     /space можно любое название папки указать.
```

В корне ФС создалась папка  `space`

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Поменял c `/dev/mapper/<user>--vg-tmp /tmp` на `/dev/mapper/<user>--vg-tmp /space`
Дальше

```
reboot
```

Проблема устранилась
UPD: После установки qtcreator-a вернул все как было, чтобы все чтобы временные файлы монтировались в /tmp

UPD 17-12-2020:
С недавних пор стала срабатывать команда `sudo mount -o remount,size=10G /tmp` , которая меняет размер /tmp. А вот в файле /etc/fstab пропала нужная для редактирования строчка.

Comment: Этим действием вы назначили другую точку монтирования и теперь временные файлы сыпятся в корневой раздел. Можно было просто эту строку закоментировать =\

Comment: @MaximTimakov я после установки все обратно вернул.

Comment: @MaximTimakov я вот только одного не понимаю: ведь /tmp тоже в корне.В чем принципиальное отличие от /space, который я создал?

Comment: `/dev/mapper/umdw--vg-*` - разные разделы на диске. тот который был подключен к `/tmp` был небольшого размера(~2 GB). перенеся точку подключения в `/space` запись временных файлов пошла в корневой раздел, где уже было больше свободного места(~5.6 GB)

Comment: @umd а в unix системах ВСЁ идёт от корня. И внешние накопители в том числе.

Answer (score 1):

У `/var` тоже похожий размер свободен.

Я бы 120ГБ вообще не делил, а то так и будет -- там много, тут мало.

Может:

- перенести данные из `/var` в `/home/var`
- отмонтировать `/var`
- убрать его из конфига, чтоб на старте не монтировался
- перенести данные обратно
- перезагрузиться

В идеале делать всё это в single-user mode, чтоб те, кто пишут в `/var` не обижались.

То же с `/tmp`, только там данные не ценные.

---

Не, не выходит, тут `/` тоже маленький.

Лучше загрузиться с флешки и ресайзить, или просто переставить.

(бакапим, если что ценное)

Comment: так и я б не делил, мне просто нужно установить qtcreator Нужно /tmp расширить

Comment: ни /var ни /tmp не расширяются

Comment: а куда им расшириться, если всё место под /home;

Comment: ну они по умолчанию маленькие и смонитрованы. а как быть раз их не расширить?

Comment: я думаю, должен быть какой-то способ научить  систему при запуске делать эти разделы больше. Ведь они по любому при каждом запуске монтируются.

Comment: расширить можно, но нужно загружаться с live-usb и запускать переразметку. хотя тут похоже [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) задействован, но в нем я не силен =\

Comment: такая же проблема были и при установке на Стандартный раздел. LVM это эскперимент. я уже несколько дней qt не могу установить. Он у меня только на CentOS встал, но цент мне не зашла чет совсем. И встает всегда на другой мой ноут, на этот все никак не встанет

Comment: как временное решение: если есть ненужная флешка: подключить ее. отрубить tmp `sudo umount /tmp` подрубить флешку как tmp `sudo mount /dev/sZX /tmp`, где `/dev/sZX` - раздел на флешке

Comment: после перезагрузки все вернется на свои места.

Comment: @MaximTimakov стопэ. Так может можно просто флеху подрубить и смонтировать в /tmp? Прост я сейчас пытался отмонтировать /tmp и это чуть нереальнее чем невозможно. Система протв чтобы я отмонтировал /tmp(таргет ис бизи, говорит). А так, да, мне только qtcreator установить

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov ни /var  ни /tmp не хоят отмонтироваться. Занятые они ребята, некогда им отмонтироваться.

Comment: попробуйте в `/etc/fstab` поправить раздел куда `/tmp` подключается: скопируйте строку и закоментируйте ее. в основной строке  в качестве раздела укажите флешку, перезагрузитесь

Comment: А так зря Вы при установке выбрали отдельные разделы для `/var` и `/tmp`. Как по мне это нужно только на серверах

Comment: single-user mode будут не заняты; хотя если LVM эксперимент, то я бы просто признал его провальным, и переставил всё на 1 раздел

Comment: @MaximTimakov ну вот  вруную я сделал один LVM / второй /boot/efi. Хз почему так произошло.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov так я изначально ставил все на один раздел(при предыдущих установках системы Fedora, Kali). Не понимаю вообще почему все равно эта лабуда вся в /tmp монтируется.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov решил свою проблему. даже не стал флешку искользавть. Просто в корне создал папку `/space`,  по совету соседа по комментам зашел в `/etc/fstab`, но ничего там не комментировал, а изменил место монтирование `/tmp` на `/space` и презагрузился. Установочка qtcreator-a пошла, полет нормальный.Возвращать обратно /tmp не буду. Папку /space точно никакая программа сторонняя юзать не будет  Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Ну, думаю, не на долго, следующим `/` переполнится. Наздоровье.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov переполнится потому что туда пишется то что должно в /tmp? Если да, то при каждом ребуте переписывается ведь

Comment: У меня тaкой же ssd примерно; раздел 1 + своп; `/var` уже 12G; тут не угадаешь